# T-SQL error when trying to insert into a temp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables, insert-into

I have a temp table I'm trying to populate from a select statement.

However I'm getting this error :

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

I have tracked it down to the column `endtime` that using the `LEAD`; if I removed this `LEAD` column, would it work?

Not sure what I'm missing

Thanks Mike

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#flextx', 'U') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #flextx; 

 CREATE TABLE dbo.#flextx
 (
     OmanId VARCHAR(255),
     MRDF VARCHAR(255), 
     status VARCHAR(255), 
     statusid BIGINT, 
     EVENT_ACTION BIGINT,
     starttime DATETIME,
     endtime DATETIME
 ) 

INSERT INTO dbo.#flextx
    SELECT 
        f.OmanId, 
        f.MRDF, 
        s.status, 
        s.statusid, 
        f.EVENT_ACTION, 
        (f.TIMESTAMP) AS starttime,
        (LEAD(f.TIMESTAMP, 1, GETDATE()) OVER (ORDER BY f.TIMESTAMP)) AS endtime 
    FROM  
        dbo.#flext f 
    LEFT JOIN  
        dbo.statues AS s ON s.flexstatus = f.JOB_STATUS_TEXT
    WHERE 
        EVENT_ACTION IN (225, 226)  
        AND s.statusid = 23 
    ORDER BY 
        MRDF, EVENT_ACTION
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a compile-time error.  Add a `GO` after the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

What is happening is that you are redefining the table.  The old definition is used when the script is *compiled*.  You should also be able to fix this by just deleting the existing version of the table.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo I think you want endtime to be the next start time that would be like this:

```
     (f.starttime) AS starttime,
      ( LEAD(f.starttime,1,GetDate()) OVER (ORDER BY mrdf, event_action) ) AS endtime
```

there is no TIMESTAMP column